# Construct a valid MySQL query using Ruby/MySQL

Tags: mysql, ruby

If using the Ruby/MSQL library I returned an object of type Mysql::Result, how would I construct a string that loops through the object and constructs a valid MySQL query? I am having trouble figuring out how to drop the final comma from the output below, and how to pass this output back to the query() method.

```
require 'mysql'
dbh = Mysql.real_connect("host", "user", "pass", "db")
res = dbh.query("SELECT name, category FROM animals")
printf "INSERT INTO animals (name, category) VALUES (\n"
res.each_hash do |row|
printf "('%s', '%s'),\n", row["name"], row["category"]
end
printf ")\n"

#Output    
INSERT INTO animals (name, category) VALUES (
    ('snake', 'reptile'),
    ('frog', 'amphibian'),
    ('tuna', 'fish'),
    ('raccoon', 'mammal'),
    )
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
values = []
res.each_row do |r|
  values << "(#{r.map{|x| dbh.quote(x) }.join(", ")})"
end
query =<-SQL
  INSERT INTO animals(name, category) VALUES
    (#{values.join(",\n")}
    )
SQL

puts query
```

Comment: Thanks very much! But how to add the single quotes?

query="INSERT INTO animals(name, category) VALUES (#{values.join(",")})"

gives

INSERT INTO animals(name, category) VALUES ((snake, reptile),(frog, amphibian),(tuna, fish),(racoon, mammal))

Comment: use normal string interpolation

Answer (score 2):

I'd use join in this case, so rather than looping, and adding a comma each time, do something like:

```
["One", "Two", "Three"].join(',')
```

You'll need to turn your hash into an array containing the elements you are interested in first, of course! Try this:

```
(res.each_hash{|row| "(#{row["name"]}, #{row["category"]})"}).join(",")
```

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this would be to:

```
    require 'mysql'    
    dbh = Mysql.real_connect("host", "user", "pass", "db")    
    res = dbh.query("SELECT name, category FROM animals")   
    stmt = "INSERT INTO animals (name, category) VALUES ("    
    res.each_hash do |row|
        stmt << "(#{row["name"]}, #{row["category"]})"  
    end    
    stmt << ")"
```

"how to pass this output back to the query() method"

```
     dbh.query(stmt)
```

Answer (score 1):

in general, if you don't want to just any Ruby magic (like .join() ), you can just loop over the array/hash by index and only add the comma if it is not the last element:

```
  if(index < array.length) string << ",\n"
```

Comment: join is ruby magic? really? s = ""; def s.foo; puts "foo"; end; s.foo is magic. instance_eval{ define_method...}} is magic. const_missing is magic.  join puts things together with another thing, which is kind of underwhelming when you think about it.

Comment: meh, call me old school. i agree that it is in the fringe of "ruby magic", but ruby magic none the less (IMHO).

Comment: How is join any less 'magic' that length or << for that matter?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the suggestions. Using Ben Hughes' example, here is the 'hashed' version:

```
values = []
res.each_hash do
  |row| values << "('#{row.map{|d,x| dbh.quote(x) }.join("', '")}')" 
  end
puts values.join(",")

query="INSERT INTO animals (name, category) VALUES #{values.join(", ")}"
dbh.query(query)
```